# asp.net or input type checkbox

Tags: html, asp.net, checkbox

If I have an input checkbox:

```
<input id="Checkbox" type="checkbox" value='<%#Eval("MapID") %>' class="chk" runat="server"/>
```

and I want to convert it to an asp.net control

```
 <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="Checkbox" class="chk"/>
```

what is equivalent to value in asp:checkBox?

Comment: You can simply use `Text` property of the Checkbox to call the values from the DB

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the `Text` property of the `Checkbox` to render the value

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="Checkbox" class="chk"  Text='<%# Eval("MapID") %>' />
```

Hope it helps